# Sum and Ranking - Excel

Tags: excel, sum, ranking

My goal is to sum the scores with removing the top 2 highest and lowest 2 scores (Row T).

I have been trying to figure out how make the number error change to zero, but am having a difficult time.

My formula is `=(SUM(D9:N9)-LARGE(D9:N9,1)-LARGE(D9:N9,2)-SMALL(D9:N9,1)-SMALL(D9:N9,2))`

Your time and help is very appreciated!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't need to display if the PLACING is 0. (ie from the previous question, placing 0 means "nothing on this row" ... so then you should be able to just do:

```
=if(r9=0,0,(SUM(D9:N9)-LARGE(D9:N9,1)-LARGE(D9:N9,2)-SMALL(D9:N9,1)-SMALL(D9:N9,2)))
```

Comment: I missed a comma in the formula and it automatically changed it to *. I found the error and it works!! Thank you so much!!